# PHP - Write console output to file AND to console?

Tags: php, file, console, ob-start

I want to write the console output to a file AND to the console itself. To write the console output to a file I'm using this:

```
ob_start();
...
...
$output = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents("cronjob.txt", $output, FILE_APPEND);
ob_flush();
```

But now I want also to print the output to the console instand of just writing it to a file. Is that possible and if yes, how can I do that?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried echo-ing `$output` ?

Comment: `ob_get_contents()` does not clear the output buffer, so this code should work as is.

Comment: At the end of the progress I see the output also on the console, but not during the execution. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to display output as you go, why are you buffering? Buffering means holding it in a buffer until you retrieve those contents.

Comment: _"How can I do that?"_ Remove the output buffering completely and just call your script piped through tee: `php file.php | tee log.txt`

Comment: how should I call it? piped through tee: php file.php | tee log.txt
What does that means?

Comment: `tee` is a program that copies input to two outputs. Run `man tee` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try bebugging tools like

1. Xdebug Link for chrome
2. Xdebug Toggler for Safari

I use these and it works pretty good.